# What is the precedence of C# version 8 .. operator?

Tags: c#, operator-precedence

I'm upgrading our MS C# 7.x parser to C# 8.  It has new syntax and operators, and most of these seem to have obvious placements in any reasonable V7 grammar.

However, there is a new binary operator that forms ranges:

```
  ..
```

But I can't find any information on where this goes in the operator precedence
hierarchy.   Realistically one would expect it be lower precedence than addition
or subtraction so one could write

```
xyz[n+k..m-k]
```

but that's just guessing on my part.

Is there a v8 operator precedence table available somewhere?

Apparantly there is no Microsoft-published grammar for version 8.  Hoping I'm wrong.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/?

Comment: Have a look at [proposal doc](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges.md) in C# lang repo

Comment: Thanks guys...  don't know why I couldn't find this.  Part of it might be not believing that "proposal" meant "this is what we actually did".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges):

> All forms of the range operator have the same precedence. This new precedence group is lower than the unary operators and higher than the mulitiplicative arithmetic operators.